# What is the best way to clean internal wood that has black marks/patches on it?

Tags: wood, cleaning

What is the best way to clean internal wood that has black marks/patches on it?

I have tried scrubbing it with hot water and sugar soap, it has made some difference but not a lot.

Is there something better that can be done?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the knots? Those are part of the wood (especially prevalent in pine, which this looks like). Or the darker areas on the upper boards? Hard to see well in that photo.... if so can you describe in more detail? Does it seem like discoloring of the wood itself or something on the surface that could be cleaned off?

Comment: @HenryJackson no I don't mean the knots. I mean the black discolouring happening near the roof, above and to the right of the window frame.

Comment: Is the wood bare, or is it varnished, polyurethaned, etc?